# A continuous (two variables or more) scalar function is not Injective?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like some help on the following question.

Let $ k \geq 2 , \: a \in \,\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{k} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Show that there exists a nonzero $\textbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ so that the map $t \mapsto g(t) := f(a + t\textbf{u})$ is not injective.

I guess it has something to do with the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: It's a bit overkill here, but you might be interested in the [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem). Note that after reducing to $k=2$ and $a=0$, the solution hinted at in Plop's answer amounts to proving and applying the theorem in the $n=1$ case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints.

1. Prove that one can assume that $k=2$, and $a = 0$.

Consider the map $h := t \mapsto f(\cos(t),\sin(t)) - f(\cos(t+\pi), \sin(t+\pi))$.

2. Show that $h$ is continuous.
3. Show that $h$ changes sign on $[0,\pi]$.
4. Show that $h$ vanishes somewhere.
5. Conclude.

Comment: This does not answer the question inside the body, but only on the title.

Comment: @Crostul Does it not? If $t\in\mathbb R$ is such that $h(t)=0$, take $u=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. Then $g(-1)=g(1)$, where $g$ is as in the question.

Comment: @A.Howells I'm not sure you can take $u=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. It seems that $u$ has to be constant therefore independent of t.

Comment: @epsilon : No, no! In order to use the strategy I suggest, you have to choose some good $t$, and then define $u$ to be $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. Not every $t$ works, but you can show that at least one works.

Comment: @epsilon What Plop said. It might also help to realize that the $t$ in his answer is different from the $t$ in the question. (Plop, maybe it would be good to edit the answer to use $s$ or $\theta$ or something instead?)